# The differences between bifurcated, divided, split and branched

Tags: synonyms

What are the differences between the verbs: bifurcated, divided, split and  branched?

Answer (score 0):

**Bifurcation** and **split** are verbs that depicts the division of something into two distinctive parts or sections. For example :

> It was a prolonged debate on an issue that caused the **bifurcation** of the party.

*'Bi'* means two, so it simply means that the party was divided into 2 groups as a result of the debate.

> The Earth rumbled and **split** as soon as he stood up.

Ignoring the dramatic statement I just made up, this means that the Earth had a crack that ran through it, dividing it into two (hypothetically).

In the other hand, **branched** and **divided** means a separation, where one real or virtual object separates into various parts or sections. This needn't be restricted to two parts.

> The river **branched** off at the valley into 8 smaller streams.

This means that the river has branched (divided) into many smaller water bodies (here, 8).

> The assets were **divided** among all the relatives.

The assets were partitioned and divided to all those who deserve it.

All the four words shows a breaking or partitioning of something that used to be one, into 2 or more parts or sections. **Bifurcation** and **split** restrict the partitioning into 2, in most cases, into two equal parts, where as **divide** and **branch** can be partitioning of a thing into many parts. But keep in mind that in most sentences, they are not interchangeable. For example, you cannot say :

> Mr and Mrs Smith **branched** off last December.

The perfect word would be '**split** up'.